# Make node.js server listen on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm building a simple app that connects to a Node.js server.

Now, I've successfully tested the server locally: I run "node server.js" on a cmd window, the server's listening, and then I can use whichever routes I'd like.

However, using "http://localhost:8080/" obviously isn't going to work on my phone, and therefore I've deployed my code to Heroku. I can run this file there, and get the reply it sends, but my question is - how do I make it continuously listen?

I tried searching for an answer online, but no luck..

here's my server.js file:

```
// dependencies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8080);
var routes = require('./routes/api');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  

//express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes
app.use('/api', routes);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Our first route is working! :)');
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Testing successful!! :)');
});

//start the server
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the instructions? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by "continuously listen". Heroku builds the project and runs when you deploy it. All you need to do is create a heroku project and push your code to instance. Monitor the logs on heroku so that you know that your project is successfully deployed and there is no error. You will have to install heroku toolbelt to execute heroku related commands. All the details for the deploying node application to heroku are provided [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#set-up)

Answer (score 0):

To send your server to heroku, follow the steps provided in this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The call to

```
app.listen(port, ...
```

does continuously listen.

Assuming your deploy worked, go to your Heroku app's url ( e.g. http://cookienator.herokuapp.com/api/test) and notice it's listening.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT,process.env.IP);
```

This may work. 
It didnt work on running port argument for me.
The above code worked for me.
Also dont forget to add app.js or start page in package.json